# Excel Macro checkboxes

Tags: excel, checkbox, excel-2007, checkboxlist, vba

I have this table

[image: table]

and, if possible using a macro, I want to:

1. when checking the box that has the value 30% it would copy to the 'Total selected" 30%
2. the user can only check one box
3. I just want when a user check the box to evaluate point1 he would choose one of the ratings (0%-30%-60%-100%) and whatever he choose will copy to the total weight value.

I don't know how to define a value for each box?

Answer (score 0):

This code should largely do the job you want. Install it in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you wish to have the action. Note that you need no check boxes on that sheet. The code is creating them. But you do need to format the cells on that sheet to display numbers (not check boxes) the way you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 01 Oct 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Specify the range where you want checkboxes to appear when clicked:-
    ' the range is defined as starting from C2 end ending
    ' at the cell in column F in the last used row in column A

    ' if column A has a fixed number of entries, like "Point 1 to Point 5"
    ' "Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row" may be replaced by a fixed row number
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "C"), _
                    Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "F"))

    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            Set Rng = Range(Cells(.Row, Rng.Column), _
                            Cells(.Row, Rng.Column + Rng.Columns.Count))
            Rng.ClearContents

            ' Column "B" is "Total selected"
            ' it is assigned the value from row 1
            Cells(.Row, "B").Value = Cells(1, .Column).Value
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            .Font.Size = 14                 ' set the font size as required
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = ChrW(254)
        End With
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrExit:
    ' the likely reason is that column A is blank.
    ' Make sure that there is an entry in column A
    ' for every row in which you may want to set a checkbox
    MsgBox Err & vbCr & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "Malfunction"
End Sub
```

I didn't understand what you want to have in the "Total weight" column. You may be able to fill that column with a worksheet function.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I have use this code:

Comment: If the code serves your purpose please mark the answer as "selected". Else, let me know which part needs improvement and I shall help.